# Explain result in for loop in php code

Tags: php

```
function random_num($num){
    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $str .= rand(0,9);

    }
    return $str;
}
for($t = 0;$t < 24;$t++){
    $xxx = random_num(2);
    $arr[$t] = $xxx;
    echo "$t. ".$arr[$t]."<br />";
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

i don't understand why i echo in loop, the result always not show $arr[0], but when the loop end, i can print this array, it show all. What problem when echo in loop? Thanks for explain :D

Comment: try moving the `echo '<pre>';` before the loop

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, can you explain a little clearer?

Comment: only $arr[0]? try $arr[]=$xxx;

Comment: Yes, $arr[0] not show when i echo in loop. after that i try to 'print_r' this array when loop end, the result is right. I don't understand why 'echo' not show right in loop. Can u explain me :)

Comment: in the loop the result begin arr[1], outsite the loop the result begin arr[0]. I don't understand why the result in the loop show wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You have failed to initialise `$str` in your function and `$arr` in the main body of your code. I'm surprised you're not seeing loads of warnings or errors. Beyond that, it seems to work. See [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/yy3n-f2ui)

Try this:

```
function random_num($num){

    // set $str to empty string before we concatenate things to it.
    $str = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $str .= rand(0,9);

    }
    return $str;
}

// Set $arr as empty array ready for new values.
$arr = array();

for($t = 0;$t < 24;$t++){
    $xxx = random_num(2);
    $arr[$t] = $xxx;
    echo "$t. ".$arr[$t]."<br />";
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```